# Mechanical wave speed and transverse wave velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

What is the relationship between a Mechanical Wave's speed of propagation, and the transverse velocity of any particle on the wave? How do you derive that relationship?
 I was informed that the relationship is :
$ v_{s}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} $, 
where $v_s$ is the velocity of propagation of wave.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research-efforts.

Comment: I have tried looking for the solution on every possible forum? I urge you to try the same.

Comment: We ***urge*** you to show us some effort by adding to the OP what you actually did to find out the answer, other than searching in ***every possible forum***.

Comment: The question mark "?" should only be used at the end of a question.

Comment: @Sathyam please be nice.

Comment: @Manishearth Copy that. In the past few days, there's been a maltitude of trivial questions where the op shows absolutely no effort to find an answer. I share my serious concerns on continuing the tag homework-and-exercises.

Comment: @Sathyam That's been going on for a while, actually, and they get closed -- flag them as you see them, leave a nice comment asking for more effort, and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the wavefunction be $$y(x,t)= A\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x- vt)\right].$$

Now,$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}= \text{Rate of change of wavefunction when time is constant}\;,\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\text{Rate of change of wavefunction when position is constant or transverse velocity}\; .$$

Now differentiate $y$ w.r.t. $x$ keeping $t$ constant.
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}A\cos\left[\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x- vt)\right]\; .$$

Then differentiate $y$ w.r.t. $t$ keeping $x$ constant.

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}= - \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\cdot v\;A\cos\left[\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x- vt)\right]\; . $$

Now, this proves $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}= -\frac{1}{v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.$$

Comment: What is the physical significance of the rate of change of wavefunction when time is constant. Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: @Garvit Sharma: Dear Gravit, you better look at derivation of  wave-equation. It would become clear to you then.

Comment: I have , I understand it as well, but it would be great if you could elaborate just a little bit more.

Comment: @Garvit Sharma: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is used to measure force on an infinitesimal part of an oscillating string.

Comment: So is my understanding correct? - when we are taking the partial derivative w.r.t x( taking time constant) , we are basically observing the change in y, at some x, at a fixed point in time right?
When we were taking this derivative w.r.t time at some fixed x, we were getting the transverse velocity. What physical quantity would ∂y/∂x represent is the question? And yes I am aware of the usage of ∂y/∂x in the derivation of the wave equation and also the intensity relation, so I get it's usage.

Comment: Well only time is constant; so you can make a little increment in $x$ & that is what $\partial x$ s all about.

Comment: @user36790 There is an error in the final equation (cannot edit, 6 character rule). I am curious, how is $ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $ *used* to calculate the force instead of $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$

Comment: @Sathyam: What I meant to say that it could be used to determine the force as it is tension times the difference of this rate at the end points of the concerned part. This evolves to one-dimensional laplacian using Taylor's series.